# Changing variable under while loop

Tags: python, loops, variables, python-3.x, while-loop

I'd like to make something like this in Python 3:

```
x = 0
while x < 20:
    variable0 = 2
    x += 1
```

The variable's name should change with every loop: 1st loop `variable0`, 2nd loop `variable1`, 3rd loop `variable2`, ...

Comment: *(**TL;DR**: Don't.)* Also, `for x in range(20):` is much neater than your current `while` loop.

Comment: Use a [list](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html)

Answer (score 0):

I would use a dict for this.

```
my_dict = dict() 
for x in range(20):
    my_dict["thing" + str(x)] = 2

for k, v in my_dict.items():
    print("{0} : {1}".format(k, v))
```